# DataGridView not being repainted

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a `DataGridView`, that I'm selectively (iteratively) hiding rows from, using `row.Visible`:

```
void UpdateMessageWindow()
{
    MessageDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MessageDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        row.Visible = DisplayedLevels.HasFlag((MessageLevel)row.Cells[3].Value);
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem that after rows are added, they're not being repainted until you either click on the cells (to redraw the clicked cell), press a key, or hide the window.  If you move the mouse over the DGV, you can see they exist, as the cursor changes.

I'm pretty sure I've tried every combination of relevant sounding methods on DataGridView, but nothing has helped.

**Edit:**
 I've modified it to use BindingSource.Filter, by adding a "Visible" column to the DataSet Table, setting `messageBindingSource.Filter = "Visible"`, and rewriting UpdateOutput to

```
void UpdateOutputWindow() 
{
    foreach (JobDataSet.MessagesRow row in _dataSet.Messages)
    {
        row.Visible = DisplayedLevels.HasFlag(row.Level);
    }
}
```

But it's still displaying the same behaviour.

Comment: Cant you apply a Row Filter? rather than iterating each row? or perhaps filter the Datasource?

Comment: The datasource is a DataSet, which doesn't support filtering, and `BindingSource.Filter` and its like don't support bitwise operators.

Comment: Cant you use DataView with DataSets?

Comment: @Derek either I'm missing something, or that has the same limitations, but see edit, using messageBindingSource.Filter doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer was to add a handler to the `DataTable.RowChanged` event:

```
_dataSet.Messages.RowChanged += delegate
                                {
                                    MessageDataGridView.Invalidate();
                                    MessageDataGridView.Update();
                                };
```

It's probably inefficient, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try focusing the DataGridView with:

```
MessageDataGridView.Focus();
```

Comment: Nope :/.  I should probably add that you need to click on each and every cell of the DGV to get them to repaint.

Comment: Is your DataGridView bound to a DataSource?

Comment: Yes, to a BindingSource, which is in turn bound to a DataSet.  I'd use `BindingSource.Filter`, but it doesn't support bitwise operators.

Comment: I would look in to filtering your results before hand so the datasource only contains records you want to be visible.